# Apply patch to solr version 5.2.1

Tags: apache, solr, classification, patch

I am a new user of Solr and I want to use [this classification module](http://alexbenedetti.blogspot.com/2015/07/solr-document-classification-part-1.html?showComment=1462285849493#c6963742037616576389) ? but I don't know how to apply the patch mentioned in the previous link.
I am working with Solr 5.2.1 on Ubuntu.
I found this [page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Working_With_Patches) that describe how to work with patches but I don't understand where to find "**your Solr trunk checkout dir**" location ? Is it the solr installation dir or another one ?
Can someone tell me the detailed manner to do that ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: thanks for reading my post.
i want to apply [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7739) patch to my solr installation but i don't know why ?
i wand a detailled tutorial or guide if exists.

Answer (score 0):

This should be executed inside the Solr rep:

1. `git clone git@github.com:apache/lucene-solr`
2. `cd lucene-solr`
3. `wget PATCH_URL`
4. `patch -p1 -i name_of_the_patch --dry-run`

After that you will have Solr with patch in `lucene-solr` folder. But you also should install this patched version to use.

Comment: There is no need to apply the patch any longer; [the code is now part of Solr](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7739) from 6.1.

Comment: @MatsLindh It's right for this patch. But for other patches in generic case it works.